# Imported module cannot be found when Python script is run via a bat file

Tags: python, batch-file

I know there has been similar problems, but unfortunately most of them are related to errors with pyperclip itself instead of the batch file, which i suspect is where the problem stems from.
Below is an MRE of my Python script:

```
#! python3 -> Do I have to use my version(3.8)?
# pw.py - An insecure password locker program.
import sys, pyperclip

#do something with the module
```

And my batch file pw.bat:

```
@py.exe  C:\Users\KEVIN\PycharmProjects\atbs_exercise\pw.py %*
@pause
```

I am running python 3.8 on windows 10. I imported the pyperclip module in my python script pw.py and ran the file via pw.bat, and this in turn gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\KEVIN\PycharmProjects\atbs_exercise\pw.py", line 7, in <module>
    import sys, pyperclip
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip'
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Which shouldn't happen as I have installed pyperclip on the project using pip, and the script itself runs just fine in pycharm. What am I missing?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I am using pycharm. So the thing is that pycharm had also installed python.exe in the project folder. And as the module pyperclip is only installed to that folder, the python.exe used in the bat must point to the one in the project folder.

Comment: Your shebang will be ignored, because you are calling with whatever `py.exe` is pointing to. Is the interpreter of the project in pycharm the same as what `py.exe` points to?

Comment: What I know is that the project interpreter is python 3.8, though i do not know where py.exe points to, as i'm following a book. What syntax should I use if I would like to call the same interpreter as in the project from the bat file?

Comment: First, you should find out where both point to. To do this, type `where py` in the `cmd` and in your pycharm, add the two lines `import sys` and `print(sys.executable)` to the top of your script and run it.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why are you using py.exe. when running commands from a batch file or cmd .you should use `python.exe`.obviously you would need to add python to add for doing so.instead of adding py.exe to path,add python in system variable `Path` which is somewhere present in `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\`(your path might be diffrernt).you can add python in Path by following this [post](https://datatofish.com/add-python-to-windows-path/)

after adding python to path just use the following batch-file:

```
@echo off
python path-to-your-py-file\filename.py
```

Comment: Let's say I need to run them using py.exe in order to avoid confusion(I am using a reference book), what directory should i add into the path so windows can search for the script? The project directory? Or the python directory?

Comment: @KevinJuan i think you might be confusing paths of py.exe and python.exe. py.exe is present in ```C:\Windows\``` and python.exe is usually present in ```C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\``` if you need to use py.exe you would need to give it's directory and if you need to use python.exe(which is usually used) you would need to give it's directory.

Comment: I am also still confused on why pyperclip doesn't work in the batch file as the error log suggests the problem lies in the module.

Comment: @KevinJuan No ,the problem doesn't lie in module.how could the porblem lie in module when it isn't found :```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip' ```